# PowerShell Memory Leak

Tags: powershell, memory-leaks

I have reopened this question because, unfortunately, I was unable to solve the problem. My script runs in the background continuously, but after minutes to hours it uses a lot more memory than after the start. The script is 3000 lines long, uses different runspaces and native .net functions. I have tried to find the memory leak by commenting out the functions, without success. It is probably a combination of the different functions. I think I really need a way to analyze the memory at the runtime. What can I do?

Comment: "What can I do?" Re-write from scratch, take note of when the memory bloat starts occuring. Then you have your [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: powershell is NOT well suited to running for long periods of time. if you need to do this, you will need to manually add calls to clean up after all your objects. a better [and far more reliable] solution is to switch to c#.

Comment: "switch to c#" I use the UniversalDashboard FrameWork so switch means develope a own solutions. Not so nice

Comment: "take note of when the memory bloat starts occuring" I did this by commenting soem parts of the script. Memory leak doesn't start at a specific point. Rewriting will almost certainly end in the same result

Comment: @fabian - if you want to reply to a comment, you need to use `@UserName` to get S-O to send a notification. kinda like what i did with the comment ... [*grin*]

Comment: @fabian - identify the areas that are using too much RAM and rewrite them in c#. PoSh can call c# at will, so your work with the UD framework will not be a blocker.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey do you have a recommendation how I identify the area?

Comment: @fabian - just the usual ... test & measure. perhaps keep one of the sysinternals utils running on your 2nd screen and take note of where the RAM use jumps. try triggering a section of code or a function, measuring the RAM use, _exiting that section of code_, and then re-measuring. as pointed out by others, it is down to the usual drudgery of detailed debugging & analysis ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey thanks, I'll try

Comment: @fabian - you are most welcome! glad to kinda-sorta help ... and i wish you the best of good luck! [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey It's so strange. There are every where some small leaks. I start on one function, step into and uncomment every thing, that raise the memory. But  there is not one step that use 50MB of ram, there are many steps which left some KB. Some times normal foreach or where-object, some times normal pscustomobject definition. It looks like the Garbage Collector dont't do his job... Do you know if a known issue  exist about GC and runspaces?

Comment: @fabian - you are well beyond my skill level. [*sigh ...*] powershell is **_really, really, REALLY not intended for running for hours_**. you will need to add explicit GC calls everywhere ... and still will have problems since PoSh depends on the managed code system to do stuff and has very little direct control over anything at all. **_from what i can tell, your only real solution is to rewrite your code - likely in c#_**. sorry for the bad news ... but you are using the wrong tool for long, LONG, **_LONG_** running code.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Yeah, I'm also afraid so. But this framework (https://universaldashboard.io/) looked like a simple and fast solution :-S And so he started his VisualStudio :-) Thanks for your support!

Comment: @fabian - you are most welcome ... and i wish you the very best of good luck! [*grin*]